# In F# what is the difference between float [] and float list?

Tags: arrays, list, f#

The compiler is indicating "This expression was expected to have type float []
but here has type float list". I thought "[]" was the syntax for a list. I can't easily simplify the code for posting but perhaps someone can create an example that would generate this error. I searched several web pages on signatures.

Comment: `float []` is a float array e.g `[|1.; 2.|]`

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why they don't use "float [||]" to avoid this type of confusion?

Comment: This will mostly have to do with the fact, that F#'s syntax is closely modeled to be compatible with OCaml, in fact under certain circumstances the same code is compatible in both languages.

Comment: @JimLewis because of dogma. As Daniel Fabian pointed out - it was just mindless copying from OCaml. There is very little sound engineering and programmer-friendly thought behind it.

Unfortunately F# isn't well designed in terms of grammar/syntax consistency or .NET lang interop. There is much more of such quirkiness in F# so you either accept it as is or learn Python or Scala.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In type annotations, `[]` denotes an array. This is despite the fact that in both patterns and expressions, it denotes lists.

When annotating lists, the syntax `float list` is usually preferred to the .NET standard notation `List<float>`, to avoid confusion with `System.Collections.Generic.List<>` (which has the `ResizeArray` type abbreviation in F#).